# Annotations for Gnome Screenshot tool

Tags: linux, gnome, screenshot

The new screenshot tool in [Gnome 42](https://release.gnome.org/42/) looks pretty neat. But most of the time, when I take a screenshot I need to highlight something by adding an arrow or text. I used to use [flameshot](https://flameshot.org/) for that, but starting with Gnome 41 <sup>[1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/merge_requests/1970) [2](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/issues/2186)</sup> it is necessary to click "Share" for every screenshot, which gets annoying.

Is there any workflow for quickly adding annotations when using the build-in Gnome screenshot tool?

With "workflow" I mean adding the annotations directly when taking the screenshot (before it goes to the clipboard or is stored, like flameshot) or at least a way automatically pipe the screenshot into another app (that opens fast).
Otherwise clicking "Share" is easier.
The best option would be to give flameshot the permission to take screenshots only once and save that setting.

Comment: Try Gnome Photos for editing.      sudo dnf install gnome-photos    ,,,,,, https://fedoramagazine.org/enhancing-photos-gnome-photos/#:~:text=sudo%20dnf%20install%20gnome-photos%20Run%20the%20app%20from,the%20pencil%20icon%20to%20open%20the%20Edit%20panel%3A

Comment: Gnome Photos looks really nice (I will probably use it for other things), but I do not see that it is a great fit for annotations

Answer (score 1):

Try "Drawing" https://maoschanz.github.io/drawing, which is specifically meant for this purpose.

Comment: Looks promising, is there a way to seamlessly integrate it in the screenshot work flow, i.e. add the annotations before the screenshot is saved or copied to the clipboard?

Comment: I'm not sure. It may be possible via a gnome shell extension

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which is worth a try is the Gnome extension [Draw On Your Screen 2](https://github.com/zhrexl/DrawOnYourScreen2)

Once installed, you press `super` + `alt` + `d` and then start drawing your annotations (right click to see drawing options). Then take your screenshot as you normally do.

Comment: I used this for a while now, it works. But the workflow is still not as smooth as I'd like it to be, and it is missing some features (pixelating, highlighting, sequence numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Annotator](https://github.com/phase1geo/Annotator).

It's an application specifically designed for annotating images and not just a general purpose image editor. For example, it's the only one from my survey having the option to easily add sequence numbers.

My workflow is:

1. Take screenshot
2. Launch Annotator
3. Paste image

Not exactly what you ask for because this workflow involves the clipboard before annotating, but anyway I think it's worth sharing.

I couldn't find it in flathub but github has instructions for [installing via flatpak](https://github.com/phase1geo/Annotator#flatpak).